# Signed APK Crash when Downloaded from Google Play Store

Tags: android, eclipse, android-facebook, android-proguard

I am using `Facebook SDK` for `Login with Facebook` in my application, app works perfectly when I use `unsigned APK` or install `signed APK` in my real device. But when I upload same signed APK on Play Store and download and run it crash with below error log.

I have already tried to add below code in my `progaurd-project.txt` file.

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

My **project.property** file is:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:22
android.library.reference.1=..\\google-play-services_lib
android.library.reference.2=..\\CircularImageViewLib
android.library.reference.3=..\\VKOpenAuthActivitySDK
android.library.reference.4=..\\android-support-v7-appcompat
android.library.reference.5=..\\FourSquareLib
android.library.reference.6=..\\..\\..\\git\\StickyScrollViewItems\\library
android.library.reference.7=..\\Cropper
android.library.reference.8=..\\FacebookSDK\\FacebookSDK
android.library.reference.9=..\\LDrawerLib
android.library.reference.10=../LinkedinSDK
```

My **proguard-project.txt** is:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
```

**Error log** is:

```
com.facebook.an: com.facebook.b.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract org.json.JSONObject com.facebook.b.c.c()
at com.facebook.b.h.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.b.f.b(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.b.f.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
at $Proxy0.c(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.internal.cj.a(Unknown Source)
at com.facebook.internal.cj.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

I have already checked my released `Keyhash` and added that on Facebook too.

Solutions that are already been tried:

1. [Signed apk crashes with facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068135/signed-apk-crashes-with-facebook-login)
2. [Android Facebook integration with proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657244/android-facebook-integration-with-proguard)
3. [Facebook and proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649143/facebook-and-proguard)
4. [Android ProGuard settings for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760581/android-proguard-settings-for-facebook)
5. [Error on exported apk - FacebookSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748716/error-on-exported-apk-facebooksdk)
6. [I got this error for first attempt to login facebook.How can solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343270/i-got-this-error-for-first-attempt-to-login-facebook-how-can-solve-this)

Comment: have you used any custom views or custom libraries

Comment: It's there in question please check

Comment: nice you have skipped facebook from applying progarud. same in that way if you are using any libraries for views, just exclude those things also.

Comment: Have you not check released APK before upload ?

Comment: Please read complete question before commenting and down voting it.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal it looks like `error` is related with `ProGuard`, try not to use `proGuard` and check if it is working

Comment: @hrskrs I have tried that too by commenting `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt` in my `project.property` file still it giving same error

Comment: try adding `-keepattributes Signature` to `proGuard`

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/a/23513809/630668

Comment: @M-D I have listed that questions into my already tried list and that mentioned solutions didn't worked, so just read complete question before marking duplicate.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal Why don't you reopen the question then?

Comment: It's different question with different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your proguard-project.txt file according below :

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.facebook.model.** { *; }

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```